# Запись строки в память

Tags: c, ассемблер

Учусь работать с отладчиком GDB - разбираю пример простой программы на языке C. Пример из учебника, так что не ругайтесь за код. Тем более что вопрос по компиляции/ассемблеру.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( )
{
    char str_a[20];
    strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
    printf(str_a);
}
```

Компилировал `gcc 11.1.0` с флагами `-g -no-pie` .
Дизассемблированный код в интересующем меня месте выглядит так:

```
...
<main+27>:  lea    rax                 , [rbp-0x20]
<main+31>:  movabs rcx                 , 0x77202c6f6c6c6548
<main+41>:  mov    QWORD PTR [rax]     , rcx
<main+44>:  mov    DWORD PTR [rax+0x8] , 0x646c726f
<main+51>:  mov    WORD  PTR [rax+0xc] , 0xa21
<main+57>:  mov    BYTE  PTR [rax+0xe] , 0x0
...
```

Пример полного дизассемблера можно посмотреть на godbolt [здесь](https://godbolt.org/z/9j1exnh61). Он чуть отличается от того, что у меня gdb выдает, но приведенная часть аналогичная.

Вопрос такой: почему первые 8 байт записываются в память в две инструкции `<main+31>, <main+41>` через использование регистра `rcx` , а оставшиеся 7 байт записываются напрямую? Могу понять, почему, к примеру, ради 1 байта нуль-терминатора нецелесообразно целый регистр какой-нибудь задействовать. Но почему в таком случае и первые 8 байт тоже не записываются напрямую по подобию других?

***** UPDATE *****

Спасибо [@Fat-Zer за ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1335300/452073). Действительно, нет такой инструкции, которая бы напрямую пересылала 64-битный константный аргумент в память. Сверился по мануалу Intel (для инструкции `mov` можно посмотреть Vol. 2B 4-35)

Также благодарность за [комментарий @Илья К](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1335265/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C#comment2363081_1335300), который указал на существующее ограничения максимальной длины инструкции в 15 байт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Но почему в таком случае и первые 8 байт тоже не записываются напрямую по подобию других?

В наборе команд `amd64` банально нет инструкции, пересылающей 64-х-битный константный аргумент команды (в отличии от 32-х-битных и меньше) напрямую в память. Поэтому приходится помещать его сначала в регистр, и только потом сохранить в память.

А две инструкции записывающие по 4 байта сразу в память, как подметил *@avp*, занимали бы, как минимум, просто больше места: `14` байт против `13`, хотя, возможно, у компилятора были и какие-то другие причины так сделать.

Почему именно такой инструкции нет — стоит спросить у инженеров AMD. Как подсказывает *@ИльяК*, одна из причин, почему такой команды нет, вероятно, в том, что для некоторых типов адресации она получилось бы слишком большой: `8` байт на адрес и `8` байт на аргумент + собственно опкод, что не поместилось бы, в частности, в `128`-ми битную шину предекодера инструкций на K8.

Comment: Скорее тут компилятор банально экономит байты. 2 инструкции, записывающие 8 байт   в память через регистр занимают (судя по листингу) 13 байт, а 2 команды непосредственной пересылки займут 14 байт

Comment: @avp, хорошее замечания — я об этом не подумал, но я рассуждал о том, почему в наборе команд в принципе нет инструкции прямой пересылки значения в память

Comment: Адресация памяти будет занимать 8 байт, пересылаемое значение будет занимать 8 байт, плюс опкод команды и длина такой инструкции превысит лимит в 15 байт на одну инструкцию.

Comment: @ИльяК, мм... неплохое объяснение, но это только при абсолютной адресации... при относительной можно и в куда меньший объём уложиться... а если не секрет, то что за лимит и откуда у него ноги растут?

Comment: Если сократить максимальную длину адресации то тогда команда не будет "универсальной", очевидно разработчики хотели этого избежать и не рискнули вводить такую команду. Уже до Скайлайка шина инструкций имеет размерность в 16 байт и читает кеш-инструкций по параграфам, очевидно с этим и связанно ограничение на максимальную длину инструкции в 15 байт

Comment: @ИльяК, нуда... звучит логично... а почему `15`, а не `16`?

Comment: Не знаю, но предполагаю, что в процессор должно всегда попадать минимум две инструкции при чем вторая может даже не уместиться в 16 байт, но от нее должен быть загружен хотя бы один байт.

Comment: @ИльяК, дополнил ответ

Comment: @avp, аналогично^